# Override method from macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Is it possible to add method definition from macro call? Here is an example:

```
object Macros { def someMacro = ...}
trait Foo { def foo:Int }
class Bar extends Foo { someMacro() }
//calls to (new Bar).foo is possible and return value defined in someMacro
```

Comment: Did you mean to have `class Bar extends Foo { *override def foo: Int =* someMacro() }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible with Scala macro annotations.  One thing that macro annotations enable is adding members to class definitions.  Since macros are compiled before other steps of type checking, you can use this functionality to satisfy a trait's constraints.

For example, the following macro annotation `@foo` adds a `foo` method to its annotated classes.  Here, the method takes no arguments and returns an `Int`:

```
object Macros {
  def fooImpl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    val fooMethod = DefDef(NoMods, newTermName("foo"), List(), List(List()), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(5)))
    c.Expr[Any](annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
      case List(ClassDef(mods, name, tdefs, Template(parents, self, body))) =>
        ClassDef(mods, name, tdefs, Template(parents, self, body :+ fooMethod))
    })
  }
}

class foo extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro Macros.fooImpl
}
```

Then you can use the `@foo` annotation to satisfy some `Trait` definition:

```
trait Foo { def foo: Int}

@foo
class Bar extends Foo //compiles
(new Bar).foo //5
```

You can read more about Macro annotations [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override an abstract method with a macro.  However, you can override a concrete method, even if that concrete method itself overrides an abstract method.  So, if you introduce an intermediary trait with a default implementation, you can have the desired outcome.  For example:

```
object Macros {
    def someMacro(c: Context): c.Expr[Int] = {
        import c.universe._
        c.Expr[Int](Literal(Constant(5)))
    }
}

trait Foo {
    def foo: Int
}

trait FooWithDefault extends Foo {
    override def foo: Int = 0
}

class Bar extends FooWithDefault {
    override def foo: Int = macro Macros.someMacro
}

(new Bar).foo //5
```

This does lead to some unexpected behavior, so be careful:

```
val b: Foo = new Bar
b.foo //java.lang.AbstractMethodError
val b: FooWithDefault = new Bar
b.foo //java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

This is explained in futher detail in the issue [SI-7657](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7657), where it is explained:

> Currently we allow macros to override non-abstract methods (in order
>   to provide performance enhancements such as `foreach` for
>   collections), and we also disallow macros to override abstract methods
>   (otherwise downcasting might lead to `AbstractMethodErrors`).
>
> This patch fixes an oversight in the disallowing rule that prohibited
>   macros from overriding a concrete method if that concrete method
>   itself overrides an abstract method. `RefCheck` entertains all
>   overriding pairs, not only the immediate ones, so the disallowing rule
>   was triggered.
>
> **Now macros can override abstract methods if and only if
>   either the base type or the self type contain a matching non-abstract
>   method.**

Comment: But what you showed is overriding method "with" a macro. I was hoping to do it from macro call as in provided example. I have read something and it is probably possible with macro annotations.